# Series expansion of $\sin(n\arccos(x))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $n=2m+1$ be an odd positive integer. Is there a clever way to prove that the Maclaurin series of $\sin(n\arccos(x))$ is equal to $$(-1)^m\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{P(n,k)}{(2k)!}x^{2k}\right)$$ where $P(n,k)=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}[n^2-(2i)^2]$.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but it might help you to look up Chebyshev polynomials, which are defined through $T_n=\cos(n\arccos(x))$.